# Test for PostgreSQL Connection without pg_isready

Tags: postgresql

From a unix command line I would like to test a PostgreSQL connection completely verifying the hostname, database, username, and password. I don't want to use `pg_isready` because that only tests the host and port. It will return an 'accepting connections' even if the database, username, and password are all wrong.

I was thinking I could use a `psql` command. For example `select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('database'));`. However, that command takes a bit of processing to return. Is there a different command I could use that is super quick? Listing all tables would not be a good choice because I have hundreds in the database. Also, something that doesn't require any knowledge of the database beforehand (i.e. table(s), datatypes, etc.). Also, something a non-root user could query.

If it makes any difference, this is an AWS Aurora PostgreSQL 12 database.

Comment: Test it from where?  From C code?  From a command line?  If you run `psql` with the command `SELECT 1;`, that will tell you whether the login works.

Comment: `SELECT version();` is lighting fast and also gives you the opportunity to check if you're connected to a database version that is supported by your software.

Comment: Thank you! Both your answers work but I like `SELECT version();` because the response seems a bit more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both @tim-roberts and @frank-heikens gave answers that worked. Thank you! I am going with Frank's

```
$ /usr/bin/psql -U username -h hostname -p port -d dbname -c "select version();"
```